# select2 run trigger select once only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to ask for you help. I am currently having a problem in select2/jquery.  I've been solving this for 1 day now.

Here is the scenario:
[Inventory Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alkbM.png)

1. I have a **customer code** and a **customer name** field(select2).
2. I can type on the **customer code** field, and once I selected a **customer code**, the **customer name** field will be automatically filled out.
3. The same with the **customer name** field, If I selected a **customer name**, the **customer code** field will be filled out.

Now, I already got it working. The problem is, I have a code that will automatically fill each field. But what happens is, it seems that if I change the **customer name** field, it will fill out the **customer code** field, and it will trigger again to change the **customer name** field, and it goes on and on. They keep on changing each other. Like a never ending loop.

My question is, how can I trigger it only once, so it would not continue in a loop.

If I change the **customer code** field, it would fill out the **customer name** field. Stop.
If I change the **customer name** field, it would fill out the **customer code** field. Stop.

Hoping for you guidance. Thank you everyone. Here is my code:

```html
$('body').on('select2:select', '.select-customer-code', function (e) {

    var data = e.params.data;
    var customer_code = data.id;
    var parent = $(this);

    /** Load Ajax */
    ajax_loader(baseUrl + 'merchandiser/inventory/manual/customer/info/fetch', {
        customer_code: customer_code
    }).done(function (response) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(response);
        var el = parent.parent().parent('tr').find('.select-customer-name');


        /** Load select2 */
        select2_loader_plain(el, customer_name_url);
        el.select2('trigger', 'select', {
            data: {
                id: response.customer_code,
                text: response.customer_name
            }
        });
    });

});


$('body').on('select2:select', '.select-customer-name', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    var parent = $(this);
    var el = parent.parent().parent('tr').find('.select-customer-code');

    el.select2('trigger', 'select', {
        data: {
            id: data.id,
            text: data.id
        }
    });

});
```

**EDIT: (ADDED THE HTML MARKUP)**

```html
<table width="100%" class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Customer Code</th>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Inventory Date</th>
      <th>Material Code</th>
      <th>Material Description</th>
      <th>UOM</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
      <th>Batch</th>
      <th>Reported By</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><select class="form-control form-select select-customer-code"></select></td>
      <td><select class="form-control form-select select-customer-name"></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><select class="form-control form-select select-customer-code"></select></td>
      <td><select class="form-control form-select select-customer-name"></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>

    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT 2: SOLUTION (answered by Tom Jenkins)**

```html
var code_lock = false;

$('.select-customer-code').on('select2:select', function (e) {

    var data = e.params.data;
    var customer_code = data.id;
    var customer_name = $('.select-customer-name');


    if (!code_lock) {

        /** Load Ajax */
        ajax_loader(baseUrl + 'merchandiser/inventory/manual/customer/info/fetch', {
            customer_code: customer_code
        }).done(function (response) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(response);

            customer_name.select2('trigger', 'select', {
                data: {
                    id: response.customer_code,
                    text: response.customer_name
                }
            });


        });

    }

});


$('.select-customer-name').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    var parent = $(this);
    var customer_code = $('.select-customer-code');

    customer_code.select2('trigger', 'select', {
        data: {
            id: data.id,
            text: data.id
        }
    });

    code_lock = true;

    setTimeout(function () {
        code_lock = false;
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: for one, I think you should be using the `change` event listener, and for two - can you please include the html markup in your question? It would be great to have a testable snippet to work with to help solve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Kinglish,  I've added the html markup. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you were to add a global variable called `recentlyChanged` then before you make a change, you check to see if it was recently changed. If it was recently changed, you do not make the changes. If it was not recently changed, set the global variable to show it was recently changed, and use `setTimeout` to delay changing it back to not being recently changed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @Tom, yes I understand. But I was thinking, what is the recommended duration for setTimeOut.

Comment: You just need to make sure that the time is longer than it takes for the code to execute.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it working, I 've applied what you suggested. You the best, man!